# Material Select Default Selected item does not work the second time

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

How do I make an Angular Material Select Component go back to its selected default after changing?
It works in initialization, but not after changing the value manully in the UI screen.

Trying to create a button, to make it return to default.
Is there way to use NgOnChanges? already using get setters.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown-cont">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
        <mat-select
            disableOptionCentering
            [disabled]="disabled"
            [ngStyle]="styles"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
            (selectionChange)="selectedItemChanged($event)"
            >
            <mat-option [value]="defaultItem[txtValue]">{{defaultItem[txtField]}}</mat-option>
            <mat-option
                *ngFor="let item of listItems"
                [value]="item[txtValue]"
            >
            {{item[txtField]}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-hint>{{hint}}</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DropdownItem, DropdownComponent } from '../dropdown/dropdown.component';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-drop-down',
  templateUrl: './drop-down.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drop-down.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class DropDownComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  //#region Members

  private _listItems = [];

  onChange: any = () => { };

  onTouch: any = () => { };

  //#endregion

  //#region Inputs

  @Input()
  set listItems(data: Array<DropdownItem>) {
    this._listItems = data;
    this.selectedItem = undefined;
  }
  get listItems() {
    return this._listItems;
  }
  @Input() label = '';
  @Input() styles: any = {};
  @Input() txtField: any;
  @Input() txtValue: any;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() defaultItem: object;
  @Input() selectedItem: DropdownItem;
  @Input() primitive = false;
  @Input() hint = '';
  //#endregion

  //#region Outputs

  @Output() selectedItemOutput = new EventEmitter();

  //#endregion

  //#region ControlValueAccessor

  set value(val) {
    this.selectedItem = val;

    this.onChange(val);

    this.onTouch(val);
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.selectedItem = obj;
    this.value = obj;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  //#endregion

  //#region Event Handlers

  selectedItemChanged(selectItem) {
    this.onChange();
    let outputData: any;
    if (selectItem.value == this.defaultItem[this.txtValue]) {
      outputData = this.defaultItem;
    } else {
      outputData = this.listItems.find(x => x[this.txtValue] == selectItem.value);
    }

    this.selectedItemOutput.emit(outputData);
  }

  //#endregion

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvudhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
<mat-select
        [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.txtValue"
        (selectionChange)="selectedItemChanged($event)" >
        <mat-option [value]="selectedItem.txtValue">
                 {{selectedItem.txtField}}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of listItems" [value]="item.txtValue" >
                 {{item.txtField}}
        </mat-option>
</mat-select>

 <button (click)="defaultState()" > Default State </button>
```

Then, in your component.ts file...

```
selectedItem = {txtValue:'d', txtField: 'default'};
listItems =[{
   txtValue: '1',
   txtField: 'one'
}]

selectedItemChanged(event){
   console.log(event.value)
}
// This method set default state of dropDown select by clicking button
defaultState(){
  this.selectedItem = {txtValue:'d', txtField: 'default'};
}
```

Comment: gave thumbs up and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks,